# Проблема с получением мультипликативно обратной с++

Tags: c++

Необходимо вычислить мультипликативно обратное к некому числу e по модулю ph. e - простое число, ph - результат функции Эйлера от некого числа. В примере e = 65537; ph = 3616319324. Заранее вычисленное верное значение - 2373062985. Своими силами и с помощью интернета я написал несколько функций для получения этого числа. Функции, использующие расширенный алгоритм Эйлера выдают одинаковый неверный результат, близкий к максимально возможному типа переменной. Функция, основанная на теореме Эйлера также выдает неверный результат, но отличный от предыдущих. В чем здесь может быть проблема?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

uint32_t xgcd1(uint32_t a, uint32_t b, uint64_t& x, uint64_t& y) {
    x = 1, y = 0;
    uint64_t x1 = 0, y1 = 1;
    uint32_t a1 = a, b1 = b;
    while (b1) {
        int q = a1 / b1;
        std::tie(x, x1) = std::make_tuple(x1, x - q * x1);
        std::tie(y, y1) = std::make_tuple(y1, y - q * y1);
        std::tie(a1, b1) = std::make_tuple(b1, a1 - q * b1);
    }
    return a1;
}

uint32_t xgcd2(uint32_t a, uint32_t b, uint64_t& x, uint64_t& y) {
    if (b == 0) {
        x = 1;
        y = 0;
        return a;
    }

    uint64_t x1{}, y1{};
    uint32_t gcd = xgcd2(b, a % b, x1, y1);
    x = y1;
    y = x1 - (a / b) * y1;
    return gcd;
}

std::vector<int64_t> euler(uint32_t x, uint32_t y) {
    std::vector<int64_t> modInverse(x + 1, 0);
    modInverse[1] = 1;
    for (int64_t i = 2; i <= x; i++) {
        modInverse[i] = (-(y / i) * modInverse[y % i]) % y + y;
    }
    return modInverse;
}

int main() {
    unsigned long ph = 3616319324;
    unsigned long e = 65537;
    uint64_t res1{}, y{};
    xgcd1(e, ph, res1, y);
    uint64_t res2{};
    xgcd2(e, ph, res2, y);
    uint64_t res3 = euler(e, ph)[e];
    std::cout << "e: " << e << '\n';
    std::cout << "ph: " << ph << '\n';
    std::cout << "right result: 2373062985\n";
    std::cout << "res1 xgcd iterative: " << res1 << '\n';
    std::cout << "res2 xgcd: " << res2 << '\n';
    std::cout << "res3 euler: " << res3 << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int q = a1 / b1;` ???

Comment: Выражения вроде `y - q * y1` могут быть отрицательными. А вы их вычисляете в беззнаковой арифметике.

Comment: Верно, не обратил внимания, что каждую вторую итерацию значение становится отрицательным. После замены типа переменных на знаковый все заработало, благодарю